# Log to file with gradle 4

Tags: file, logging, gradle, output

Until gradle 3, I used this to write gradle's output to a logfile:

```
def fileLogger = [
    onOutput : {
        File logfile = new File( 'gradle.log' )
        logfile << it
    }
] as org.gradle.api.logging.StandardOutputListener

gradle.useLogger( fileLogger )
```

This does not work with with gradle 4.

Answer (score 7):

Update for Gradle 5:
It works when using `logging.addStandardOutputListener` instead `gradle.useLogger` and adding it to all tasks:

```
// logger
def fileLogger = [
        onOutput: {
            File logfile = new File('gradle.log')
            logfile << it
        }
] as org.gradle.api.logging.StandardOutputListener

// for configuration phase
logging.addStandardOutputListener(fileLogger)

// for execution phase
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.allTasks.each { Task t ->
        t.doFirst {
            logging.addStandardOutputListener(fileLogger)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to put that in a task to prevent its execution during configuration all the time.  For a build server build the cost is well worth it.  For an IDEA triggered build it may needlessly slow things down.  Been there, done that.